# Intellisense and problems window stops working after update of C#-DevKit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, c#-devkit

After the update of C#-DevKit neither Intellisense nor the Problem Window work.
The Problem Windows is always empty, even if there are warnings and errors are shown after `dotnet build`

I'm using a a solution with multiple projects.
Intellisense partially works only when it's used in the same file, but not when a class/method is in another file or project.

I tried to reinstall the C#-DevKit, I tried to install different older versions (I don't know which version was installed before I update).
But nothing solves the problem and I can't see any hints or error messages in any of the output windows.

It's the second time I made the mistake to update the C#-DevKit, if I can solve the problem, then I will never try it again.